# Proper way of configuring serial output with stty

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, embedded

I have a problem with properly configuring an emulated serial port on my Ubuntu machine. The setup is quite simple. I have microcontroller (BMG220p by Silicon Labs) attached via USB to my machine. The µC is properly identified as a tty at `/dev/ttyACM0`. My goal is to send some binary data from a bash script to the device.

The script is fairly simple so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

while getopts p: flag
do
        echo -n "$flag: "
        case ${flag} in
                p) ttyPort=${OPTARG}
                   echo "Use tty $ttyPort";;
        esac
done

printf "%b" "\x02\x11\x22\x33\x44\x0Akaefer\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x07\x03\x04" > $ttyPort
```

The embedded application will read 32 bytes off the UART input and parse the data according to my needs.
When I run the script for the first time I recieve the proper 32 bytes of information. However, every subsequent execution shifts my data by 3 bytes.
I assume somewhere the driver for `/dev/ttyACM0` appends some control characters to my data.
The output provided by `stty` looks like this:

```
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>;
start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel
-iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho
-extproc
```

I was already able to disable the replacement of LF with a CR+LF when writing to the serial port. However, I can not get rid of the trailing bytes.

Any idea on the proper settings is highly appreciated.

The transfer of data works also perfectly fine with screen. So alternatively I would be perfectly happy for a method to send essentially binary data over a serial port with screen from a shell script.

Best regards.

Comment: "*I would be perfectly happy for a method to send essentially binary data*" -- Then instead of using canonical mode (your termios config has OPOST and XON/XOF handshake enabled! ), try using `stty raw -F /dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your reported problem "*of the trailing bytes*". "*I assume somewhere the driver for /dev/ttyACM0 appends some control characters to my data*" -- You assume incorrectly; device drivers aren't in the habit of inserting (or removing) data bytes. "*The output provided by stty looks like this: ...*" -- How did you achieve such a bizarre termios configuration? When I use your termios config with your `printf`, instead of 32 bytes or 32+3 bytes, only 31 are received (the 0x11 is removed by the receiving XON/XOF handler as specified by IXON).